# Drop down list add value instead of replace

Tags: excel

Today I faced to a really odd problem.
When I click to the drop down list and select an item, the value add and separate with comma to the last value in cell instead of replace with the last one.

I attach a pic.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Check whether you have any VBA addin or not. Its happening because of VBA Change Event